# TypeORM "OR" "AND "operator combination

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm not sure how to use the OR condition in typeOrm where clause, could not find solution so far.

I have a db call as follows

```html
db.getRepository(MyModel).find({
where:{
  type : "new",
  status: "A"
  region: "central"
  zip_code: "4831"
  }
  })
```

I need to modify the above call same as to below SQL query

```
select * from model where type="new" and status="A" and (region="central" or zip_code="4831");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use query builder for that but if the goal is to use only the find operation you can do the following

```js
db.getRepository(MyModel).find({
  where: [
    {
      type : "new",
      status: "A",
      region: "central"
    },
    {
      type : "new",
      status: "A",
      zip_code: "4831"
    },
  ]
})
```

When you provide the list of `where` conditions it is considered as `OR` operation.

Although the end result is the same, this won't produce the exact query you desire. It would be

```sql
select * from model 
  where 
    (type="new" and status="A" and region="central")
  OR  
    (type="new" and status="A" and zip_code="4831")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the createQueryBuilder of typeorm. You can check the use of bracket [here](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder). You can use orWhere wherever you need to use the OR condition. By your query, you can use the below code:

```
createQueryBuilder("MyModel")
  .where("MyModel.type = :type", { type: "new" })
  .andWhere("MyModel.status = :status", { status: "A" })
  .andWhere(
    new Brackets((qb) => {
      qb.where("MyModel.region = :region", {
        region: "central",
      }).orWhere("MyModel.zip_code = :zip", { zip: "4831" });
    })
  );
```

This will result in the SQL query:

```
select * from model where type="new" and status="A" and (region="central" or zip_code="4831");
```