# How can I write a SQL query in typeorm in the form `SELECT * FROM t WHERE (Z AND (X OR Y))`

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I want to write a SQL query in TypeORM, something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (Z AND (X OR Y))
```

I try something like

```
[ {Z: true, 0: [{X : true, Y: true }] } ]
```

but it doesn't work because there's no column '0' in the database.

How can I write a SQL query in TypeORM like that?

Comment: could you show the whole code where you build your query?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This other question on stackoverflow might answer your question: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581933/typeorm-or-and-operator-combination). It's 1yo so I can't say whether there have been any modifications with regards to this matter. Sincerely I haven't tried TypeORM yet. But as of the time of that answer you could either repeat parameters or user the query builder with brackets.

Hope it helps. I know how horrible it is to be stuck on the limitations of an ORM, Sequelize was and still is a real pain for me.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for me. It does not produce the query I want but something alike. I couldn't find any other way to do it while looking on typeorm repo.